# css call to action right of header

Tags: css

I am wanting the phone number of this site to be on the right above  the last navitem rough I have tried the following css

```
.navbar .brand .contact {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'PT Sans';
  display: block;
  min-width: 200px;
  float:right;
  margin-top: 13px;
}
```

But it not working also do you now how I would ge the phone number information to work in responsive so it floats when resized the theme is responsive as is.

http://parkavenuelasertreatment.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the problem now, instead of positioning absolute (would break responsive design)

Take the `<span class="contact">` and put it directly inside `<div class="container">`

Like this:

```
<div class="container">
              <!--  =========================================  -->
              <!--  = Used for showing navigation on mobile =  -->
              <!--  =========================================  -->
            <span class="contact">
                      (212) 683 7034<br>
                      (212) 683 7757<br>
                      40 Park Avenue, Suite 5<br>
                      New York, New York, 19916<br>
            </span>
```

Then remove ".navbar.brand" from your css CSS like this:

```
.contact {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'PT Sans';
    min-width: 200px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 13px;
}
```

Already tested on my console, this should do the trick!

BONUS: I advise to split the info into 2 different spans, to make it fit!

Comment: still the same position im afraid im using hairpress theme by the way

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `float: left` from `.navbar .brand {}`

Comment: The float left on the .navbar .brand  is forcing the width not to take up 100% of its parent.

Comment: that would wreck the respnsive nature of theme?? and its stil doesnt float 100% where i want it

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
.contact {
    position: absolute;
    right: 40px;
    top: 5px;
}
```